# CORBA VMS how to write the method?

Tags: c++, corba

I´m learning to write a Management of digital media with CORBA.
I don´t know how to implement the Method VMSgetMediaAvailable () raises (ServerException).

**Here is the VMS.idl**:

```
module VMS {

 enum Genre { g_undefined, SciFi, Comedy, Action, Horror, Docu };
 enum StatusType { s_undefined, available, lent };

struct VMSMedia {
long   ObjectId;
long   ProviderId;
Genre  Type;
string Title;
string ProductionCountry;
short  ProductionYear;
short  Length;
StatusType Status;
};

struct VMSProvider {
long   ObjectId;
string Name;
string FirstName;
long   ZIPCode;  /* short does not work */
string Address;
};

exception ServerException {
string reason;
};

typedef sequence<VMSMedia>    VMSMediaSeq;
typedef sequence<VMSProvider> VMSProviderSeq;

interface VMSRepository {
readonly attribute long currentMaxProviderId;
readonly attribute long currentMaxMediaId;    

oneway void save ();

oneway void addProvider (in VMSProvider p);
oneway void delProvider (in long id);    

VMSProvider getProvider (in long id) 
  raises (ServerException);
VMSProviderSeq getProviders () 
  raises (ServerException);

oneway void addMedia (in VMSMedia p);
oneway void delMedia (in long id);    


VMSMedia getMedia (in long id) 
  raises (ServerException);
VMSMediaSeq getMediaOfType (in Genre type) 
  raises (ServerException);
VMSMediaSeq getMediaYoungerThan (in short year) 
  raises (ServerException);
 //here new Method
 VMSMediaSeq getMediaAvailable () raises
 (ServerException);

  };
 };
```

All I have is this in the Class Repository_i.cc:

```
 void
 VMSRepository_i::VMSMediaSeq getMediaAvailable () {

  }
```

I know I have to create a new Stub and a new Skelton in that IDL file and I have to implement this method. 
I need to ask if there is Media available, so i have to do a if- Statement right?
But I don´t know how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

`getMediaAvailable()` implementation will need to populate the sequence of
`struct VMSMedia`. You have to use OS/library calls to find out what is available and populate the sequence.

Google around to find out how to populate a sequence in CORBA, that won't be to hard.